# Different syntaxes to declare arrays: with and without the dimension statement

Tags: arrays, syntax, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm using `gfortran` version 7.2.0. I'm quite new to Fortran. I know there are different versions of Fortran. In the code below, I'm declaring arrays (or actually tensors) using different syntaxes

```
program arrays
    implicit none

    integer :: m(3, 4)
    integer, dimension(3, 4) :: n

    print *, "m = ", m
    print *, "n = ", n

end program arrays
```

In one case, I'm using the `dimension` statement, in the other I am not. This program compiles (without errors). I'm using the `gfortran`'s flags `-g` and `-fbounds-check`. The file extension of the file with the program above is `f.90`.

Why are there different syntaxes to apparently declare arrays in Fortran? Which versions of Fortran support which syntaxes, or is the possibility to declare the *rank*, *shapes* and *extents* of arrays as for `m` just an extension of the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statements

```
integer :: m(3, 4)
integer, dimension(3, 4) :: n
```

are both standard Fortran since Fortran 90.  Without the use of the `::` the first line like

```
integer m(3,4)
```

would be valid before Fortran 90.

Before coming to something else, the `,dimension` isn't a dimension *statement* but an attribute specification.  A dimension statement would be

```
dimension n(3,4)  ! With n implicitly or explicitly typed elsewhere
```

The important thing here is that attributes specified with type declaration apply to (almost) *all* objects declared.  So

```
integer :: m1(3,4), m2, m3
integer, dimension(3,4) :: n1, n2, n3
```

sees `m1` a rank-2 array, but `m2` and `m3` scalars (unless given array properties elsewhere or are actually functions) whereas `n1`, `n2` and `n3` are all rank-2 arrays of shape `[3,4]`

The two declarations of the question could then be simply

```
integer, dimension(3,4) :: m, n
```

The "almost" comes from the fact that we can have

```
integer, dimension(3,4) :: n, p(5)
```

where the shape of `p` is `[5]`, overriding the `[3,4]` specified earlier.